# Using Czech republic (European) Postcodes in CartodDB?

Tags: carto, geocoding, postal-code, czech-republic

I have dataset with columns country (contains only one country "Czech republic") and postcode (contains postcodes in NNNNN format) and other two cols (date and total). However when I try to use feature to geocode data by postcode and country its giving me result, that no data were geocoded.

Are European postcodes supported for this feature?

Comment: please check below link. It might helpful to you
http://www.upu.int/en/resources/postcodes/universal-postcoder-database.html

Answer (score 1):

You could try and enter the country in the free text field. Use the iso3 code for Czech Republic: CZ

Also, `UPDATE table_name SET country='CZ'` and retry the geocoding could work.

Find a list of countries where postal code geocoding is available [here](https://github.com/CartoDB/data-services/tree/master/geocoder/postal-codes#postal-code-geocoder-points)